# Node deletion given a string input

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new here. I need to ask you all regarding linked list, specifically about deleting node from any position given a string input. This code that I made supposedly be able to do the task...

```
void popMiddle(struct data **head, struct data **tail, char name[])
{
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Data to Delete\n");
    }

    else if(*head == *tail)
    {
        if (strcmp((*head)->name, name)==0)
        {
            free(*head);
            *head = *tail = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            printf("No Data to Delete\n");
        }
    }

    else if (strcmp((*head)->name, name)==0)
    {
        struct data *curr = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct data *curr1 = *head;
        struct data *curr2;

        while (strcmp(curr1->next->name, name)!=0 && curr1 !=NULL)
        {

            printf("%d\n", curr1);
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        }

        if ( curr1->next != *tail )
        {
            curr2 = curr1->next;
            curr1->next = curr2->next;
            free(curr2);
            curr2 = NULL;

        }

        else if (curr1->next == *tail)
        {
            free(*tail);
            *tail = curr1;          
            (*tail)->next= NULL;
        }

        else  
        {
            printf("No Data to Delete\n");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the linked list I have been working with:

Sarah-> John-> Gordon

I wanted to delete a node that contains "Jack". However as you know it, it doesn't exist in the linked list. Hence, the output should have been "No Data to Delete". Unfortunately, the console won't print anything... I have suspected that it was the loop.But I need to know where did it go wrong... Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I need to know how to make sure the code traverse through every single node while comparing it with a string input. I'm kind if stuck in figuring out how the code will reach the   `else`  clause.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that your program *crashes*, and it's because of the loop

```
while (strcmp(curr1->next->name, name)!=0 && curr1 !=NULL)
```

There are two errors here:

1. The order you do the comparisons. The logical AND operator `&&` will always evaluate the left-hand side first, which means that you will dereference the pointer `curr1` when it's `NULL`. You need to change the order of the two comparisons to check for `curr1 != NULL` first.
2. The second problem is that you don't check if `curr1->next` is a null pointer, which means that already on the last node in the list you will dereference a `NULL` pointer.

I suggest you change your loop to *begin* with the second node in the list, and during the iteration check the "current" node instead:

```
struct data *curr1 = (*head)->next;

while (curr1 != NULL && strcmp(curr1->name, name) != 0)
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *) curr1);  // Changed to the format specifier %p, to print pointers
    curr1 = curr1->next;
}
```

After this loop `curr1` will be either a `NULL` pointer if the name wasn't found. Or a pointer to the node containing the name:

```
if (curr1 == NULL)
{
    printf("No Data to Delete\n");
}
else
{
    // Node found, remove it
}
```

---

Now to help you with the removal itself, for this you need to keep track of the *previous* node, which can be done by modifying the loop like

```
struct data *curr = (*head)->next;
struct data *prev;
while (curr != NULL && strcmp(curr->name, name) != 0)
{
    prev = curr;  // Keep track of the previous node
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

Now it's easy to unlink the `curr` node from the list:

```
prev->next = curr->next;
```

And of course add a special case to see if we remove the tail:

```
if (prev->next == NULL)
    *tail = prev;
```

With some more changes you don't need to have the checks for `*head == *tail` or `strcmp((*head)->name, name)==0`. These cases can be put into the more generic case with the loop actually.

Putting it all together your function could be something like

```
void popMiddle(struct data **head, struct data **tail, char *name)
{
    struct data *curr = *head;  // Start iterating at the head
    struct data *prev = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL && strcmp(curr->name, name) != 0)
    {
        prev = curr;  // Keep track of the previous node
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Data to Delete\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Unlink node
        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            // Removed node was the head
            *head = curr->next;

            if (*head == NULL)
            {
                // We removed the last node in the list, it's now empty
                *tail = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = curr->next;

            if (prev->next == NULL)
                *tail = prev;  // Removed the tail
        }

        // Free the found node
        free(curr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really love your insight!